# Passing list members into a function

Tags: c#, list

How would I pass a list of values into a function, where the values are already stored in a list and the function isn't the same every time?

To explain, I've got a list of several different types of custom objects (A `List<object>` to make this work)  and I want to pass those objects into a function. However, the function isn't always the same. I could have several different functions, and, assuming that List's contents will always match the function's input variables, I want to be able to pass the list's contents into my function.

The following code is an example of what might work, but for one flaw:

```
List<object> myListOfVariables = new List<object>();
myListOfVariables.Add("Hello, world!");
myListOfVariables.Add(10);

void SayHelloXTimes(string helloString, int x) {
    for(int i = 0;i<x;i++) {
        print(helloString)
    }
}

SayHelloXTimes(myListOfVariables[0], myListOfVariables[1]);
```

Now, since I know my list will always contain the right amount of variables in the right positions, that would work, if I only had one function. But the problem is, I need to expand this so I could take apart my list and pass it into functions with different amounts of parameters.

For other reasons, I know my list will always have the right amount of variables in the right positions, so we don't need to worry about that. I'll also know the name of the function I need to pass my values into. I suppose I could do a load of `if` statements depending on the length of my list, like this:

```
if (myListOfVariables.Length == 2) { 
    SayHelloXTimes(myListOfVariables[0], myListOfVariables[1]); 
}

else if (myListOfVariables.Length == 3) {
    SayHelloXTimesForY(myListOfVariables[0], myListOfVariables[1], myListOfVariables[2]);
}
```

However, this (obviously) is really clunky code and I'd like to avoid it at all costs. Is there another solution to my problem? I know this is really confusing, but I did my best to explain it. If you're still confused as to what I'm trying to do, please let me know.

And no, this is not a homework problem. ;)

Comment: why don't you just pass the list itself?

Comment: I would have done that in a heartbeat but I can't for reasons that would take another five to ten paragraphs to explain. :) Make a long story short, I'm (attempting) to create a very basic API for something and I don't want to constrain potential users to using lists of objects for their function parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, so I'll assume no for now. I'll have to look IEnumerables when I have time and get back to you on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think want you want to do can be done using reflection. Look at **[MethodBase.Invoke Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx)**

All you have to do is add all the parameters in the order the function expects to an object array.

```
    class Program
    {

        public static void SayHelloXTimes(string helloString, int x)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(helloString);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MethodInfo Method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("SayHelloXTimes");
            Method.Invoke(null, new object[] { "foo", 3 });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That looks promising, I'll have to check it out and see if it's suitable for my situation. Thanks!

Comment: How and why are you using `var` in your C# example code? Does the `typeof` statement immediately after have anything to do with it?

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes sense now. A little JS-style type inference snuck in there, did it? :p

Comment: The var keyword implicitly declares a variable inferring the type from the right side of the = sign.

Comment: Oh, C# *does* have that feature? I thought that that wasn't available in C#. Well, you learn something new every day! 

So does that mean I could do this: `var myInt = 5;` and it would automagically make my variable an int?

Answer (score 0):

You want [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
void SayHelloXTimes(params string[] list) {
    for(int i = 0;i<list.Length;i++) {
        print(list[i])
    }
}



SayHelloXTimes("Hi", "Hi", "Hi"); // legal
SayHelloXTimes("Hi"); // legal
SayHelloXTimes("Hi", "Hi", "Hi", "Hi", "Hi", "Hi"); // still legal
```

Comment: See my comment on the original question and/or correct me if I've misunderstood something. :)

Comment: If the difference between functions is only number of parameter, using params word would be the best solution.

Comment: With the params keyword, you call you function with however many strings you want.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Alas, I don't think this is the solution for me; however, thanks for trying! :) (The reason being, I don't want to have anybody using my API restricted to using the `params` word in their function declarations...)

Answer (score 0):

If this were my application, I would create a parameter class to hold the list values.

You could pass the list into the class' constructor and either extract it into class-local properties (since you know the positions) or you could expose the values as readonly property directly from the list.

You can then just pass an instance of the parameter class to each of the methods and not have to worry about the number of parameters to the methods.